# Security of website with user's pages: folders or subdomains?

Tags: security, directory, subdomain

The client wants to make the site (webservice, as he named it), where users can create their own pages, including  with JS scripts, etc. I see two ways - using the folders:

```
http://service.com/user/name/ ...
```

and subdomains:

```
http://user.service.com/...
```

Both paths are not the problem, but the client wants to make it using folders for SEO benefits.
I think if I use folders, it will make the site less secure. For example, user can send AJAX request from its page and the server will respond him. If it was a sub-domain, in accordance with the SOP (Same Origin Policy) request would be rejected. Correct if I'm wrong.

Is it real problem with SOP for folders?
Are there any other security issues for folders?
Is it safer to use subdomains?

Comment: Letting users upload their own scripts, pages etc. will lead you to way more security issues than just knowing if they'd better use a subdomain or not..

Comment: Yes, I know that this will be an interesting experience )
Though, it is their own business what they will upload to their pages. I worried about server security with using user's pages. Is it possible to get SOP with folders? Please, tell other problems I might face with.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing study this issue. As I understood, in case of using folders user also can create page with Black Hat SEO and search Engines will ban my domain. Am I right?

So I can already see 2 security issue in folders and no way to fix it. Are there solutions for it? Are subdomains really more safer or they have other issues?